# Update server endpoints while migrating to FCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019.
My question is, what happens if the server endpoint is not updated post the dead-line. I already have apps that are using Push Notification on store and do not want to alter anything. Will the server be able to send the notifications with endpoint (gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/) after the mentioned date?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [Firebase Google blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html):

> As long as users have GCM logic in their apps, they will still receive
>   messages. FCM is backwards compatible with GCM, so even if you don't
>   update your server endpoint now, you can still update your app's
>   logic, and vice versa.

This will answer your question if the server will be able to send the notifications if it is not updated.